# unespected Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred error using generics

Tags: swift, generics, codable

testing some code from HakingWithSwift.com

I'd like to make generic extension on FileManager, everything ok with encoding, but I got error with myDecoding func:

> Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

here how I call those functions

```
do {
    _ = FileManager.default.MyEncode(fileName: "message.txt", data: "my message")
    }
                
FileManager.default.myDecode(fileName: "message.txt")
```

here my entire extension

```
extension FileManager {
    
    
    private func getDocumentsDirectoryPath() -> URL {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        return paths[0]
    }
    
    
    func MyEncode<T: Codable>(fileName: String, data: T) -> T? {
        let url = getDocumentsDirectoryPath().appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        
        do {
            let encoded = try encoder.encode(data)
            
            do {
                try encoded.write(to: url) 
                do {
                    let input = try String(contentsOf: url)
                        print("letto: \(input)")
                    } catch {
                        print("❌ no imput: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                
                print("✅ encoded ok")
            } catch {
                print("❌ write failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        } catch {
            print("❌ encoded failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    func myDecode<T: Codable>(fileName: String) -> T? {
        
        let url = getDocumentsDirectoryPath().appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        
        do {
            let savedData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            do {
                let decodedData = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: savedData)
                print("✅ decoded ok")
                return decodedData
            } catch {
                print("❌ decoding failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        } catch {
            print("❌ no data at url: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Think about it: How can the compiler know what `T` should be in the decoding call? You have to assign the return value to a (annotated) variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mean the error message kinda says it all.

How would Swift know what type to decode that to? You need to specify that because Decoding depends on the actual type it wants to decode

You can specify the type like this. Just replace `T` with the Type you are expecting. `String`, or whatever

```swift
let data: T = FileManager.default.myDecode(fileName: "message.txt")
```

Comment: More precisely, the type must be an *optional* (e.g. `let data: String? = ...`).

Comment: Generics are new to me. My issue is that even if I thought about it, and it is clear the problem is about T being undefined at the end of the process, I'm asking for a standard and accepted solution, I thought I was missing something inside the  decoding code. I still don't understand how smart swift is understanding and handling generics. thank you for help, above all regarding the String? part. now I'm using `let data: String? = FileManager.default.myDecode(fileName: "message.txt")
                print(data ?? "unknown")`